# How to export an x64 only package in vcpkg?

Tags: c++, vcpkg

I have create a prebuilt package using `vcpkg create` command and then installed it on my system. I then tried to export this package so I can use it on other systems using the following command :

```
vcpkg export my-lib-static --zip
```

but this complains about the fact that the x86 version is not installed and I need to install it. This is not possible as we only deal with x64 binaries. How can I get around this issue and export my x64 only library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, the command that I wrote was wrong.
Since I have previously installed my lib like :

```
vcpkg install my-lib-static:x64-windows
```

I had to export it in the same manner that is :

```
vcpkg export my-lib-static:x64-windows --zip
```

Not specifying the architecture and platform, means using x86-windows and hence the error I got earlier.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax for the new command is:

vcpkg export pkg1 pkg2 ... --[options]
You have several options for the export format:

- –zip
- –7zip
- –nuget
- –raw (uncompressed folder)

When you specify a package to export, all its dependencies are also included in the exported archive. This means the exported packages can stand on their own – no additional dependencies are required.